# Warning: type does not have a constructor with parameters of types Form issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have class `A` that inherits from `UserControl`:

```
public class A : UserControl
{
  private Form1 _form; // class Form1 : Form { //... }

  private A() 
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  public A(Form1 form) : this() 
  {
     _form = form;
  }
}
```

And visual code designer creates code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   this.a = new A((Form1)this); // here I myself added foo object in ctor
   //...
}

private A a;
```

And I have got an error:

```
Warning 1 Type 'A' does not have a constructor with parameters of types Form. 0 0
```

What I did wrong ? And how to avoid this ?

**EDIT**

The problem is that I need to know reference to the parent(in my case `Form1`) in ctor, I cant use `.Parent` property because the `.Parent` property is not set until after the ctor is done, that is why I had chosen this convoluted way to pass the parent in ctor.

The problem isn't solved yet

Comment: What are you actually trying to do because this looks like a convoluted mess?

Comment: It's bad practice to have a user control that knows about it's container like this.  Chances are you should be exposing whatever information the form needs through events or public properties, rather than having the user control actually know about it.

Comment: The usercontrol should already know about it's container via the .Parent property.. though that may be a panel or other container.. not nessecarily a form.

Comment: @Dan-o, I tried to pass `_form = (Form1)this.Parent` in the `A`ctor, and got `NullReferenceExpation` when call `_form.MyMethod()`, what I did wrong ?

Comment: @Austin Salonen, I acctually need a reference from my user control object to parent `Form1`

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect the `Parent` property is not set until after the ctor is done.

Comment: @Dan-o, you are right, but what if I need to know `Parent` property in ctor, is there any way ?

Comment: @Austin Salonen, see edit please

Comment: @William And why do you need the instance of the parent in the constructor?  I'm willing to bet that whatever you're doing, you probably don't need it and shouldn't be trying to get it at all.

Comment: @Servy, How else am I suppose to get data from `Form1`(MainwWindow), for example - `textbox.text`, and pass it in the new form (in my case tool window), and I need to get the text, pass and remember as a new window's member in the ctor of new form

Comment: @William Give the child form a property of type `string`, and in `Form1`, after creating the child form, set that property to the value to `textbox.Text`'s value.  If you need it in the constructor than add a `string` parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost answered your own question.

> The problem is that I need to know reference to the parent(in my case Form1) in ctor, I cant use .Parent property because the .Parent property is not set until after the ctor is done, that is why I had chosen this convoluted way to pass the parent in ctor.

The InitializeComponent method is called from the constructor of Form1 and inside InitializeComponent you are trying to get a reference to 'this'. I think the problem is 'this' hasn't been created yet (because you're still in it's constructor).

As somebody already mentioned, one way to deal with it is to use interfaces.

```
public class A : UserControl
{
  private MyInterface _myInterface; 

  private A() 
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  public A(MyInterface myInterface) : this() 
  {
     _myInterface = myInterface;
  }
}
```

And then have your form implement the interface.